# Get specific corner co-ordinates of UIView/UIImageView irrespective of its rotation

Tags: swift, uiview, uiimageview, cgpoint

I have a simple `UIImageView` of in my screen as follow:

[image]

To get the co-ordinates of highlighted corner of this `UIImageView`, I use simple formula:

`CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(imageView.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(imageView.frame))`

Now I rotate this `imageView` and it looks as follows:

[image]

After this rotation, how can I get the co-ordinates of this highlighted point? Because after rotation, the previous code is not applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consult the next link topic: **Transformation of Coordinates Involving Rotation**

https://www.math10.com/en/geometry/analytic-geometry/geometry1/coordinates-transformation.html

It only applies cos and sin functions to calculate (x,y) in the new rotated coordinate system. All you need is the rotation angle.

Comment: Is there any other option without using angel?

Comment: @TheRohanSanap I'm really not sure if there is another way. You can make a library for it but I still think you would need to do the math.